# Checking if a div class is present to hide another div

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I'm trying to get my div to hide if another div is present and after looking at examples online, I'm not sure what  I'm doing wrong on this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
$('#required-field').toggle(!$('#gform_confirmation_message_1').length);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gforms_confirmation_message" class="gform_confirmation_message_1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <div id="gform_confirmation_wrapper_1" class="gform_confirmation_wrapper ">
    <div id="gform_confirmation_message_1" class="gform_confirmation_message_1 gform_confirmation_message">
      Thank you for contacting us. We will make every effort to respond to you inquiries shortly.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="required-field">* Required Fields</div>
```

Comment: I wrote an answer but it's hard to incorporate your actual code without more information, like you HTML or a JS Fiddle.

Comment: Can you demonstrate this not working, it looks like it should...

Comment: I can't see why my code nor @Dan code won't work either.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/9esvtakc/, as does the JS you provide.  Check your console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `length` to check if a div is present.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if($("#gform_confirmation_message_1").length > 0){ 
        $("#required-field").hide();
    }
});
```

If `#gform_confirmation_message_1` is present, then hide `#required-field`.

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9esvtakc/)**

Comment: that is so weird, I see yours works in the fiddle but that doesn't work for me either. I tried again and both divs are still showing. Might be a caching issue. Let me check that